# Using a database request in a custom helper Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using a laravel custom helper to print data in my view blade file. I pass a foreign key from a table to the custom helper and the custom helper checks the foreign key and returns its associated data. Recently my colleage suggested it is a bad idea to use a custom helper in a foreach loop of a view file. I didn't experience any performance issues, however my colleague suggested that when uploading to an AWS server, each request to the database would be charged. This is my code:

```php
<?php
  foreach($data as $key => $details) { ?>                                            
    <td>{{ helper::getstatename($details>stateid)}}</td> 
  <? }
?>
```

This is the helper file:

```php
public static function getstatename($id) {
  $getstatename = states::select('statename','id')->where('id',$id)->first();
  if($getstatename){
    return $getstatename->statename != '' ? $getstatename->statename : '';
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

My controller:

```php
public function index() {
  $locations = DB::table('locations')->select('locations.id','locations.locationname','cityid','stateid','countryid','locations.status')
    ->where('locations.status','!=',2)->orderBy('id','desc')->get(); 
  return view('location/listlocation',['data'=>$locations]);
}
```

So I want to know, is this practice of using a helper file bad? Or should I stick to using a left join and print that data?

Comment: what is `$data`   ? model collection? , why you don't use `with` to get state name?

Comment: You are better off passing all the ids in your helper and returning them at once.  function getstatename($id_array) {} returning an array of statenames and then looping

Comment: $data consists of array of data ,does using eloquent or left join cause slowing ? @MortadaJafar

Comment: load edger is best approach to get this data .. use `with('state')` to get all datum with its state

Comment: if you see my controller ,you can see im pasing data of state,city,country,if i use with then i have to use 3 models (state,city,country) will it slow down data ? @MortadaJafar

Comment: buy load edger laravel orm will execute 3 query(not join),
but by using helper function you will need execute query for every datum record

Answer (score 0):

better you use joins to get state name at the $locations in the controller itself

Comment: for eg i have to join 3 or more tables if i use helper i can easily do it

Comment: you can do it apparently  like this.

$shares = DB::table('shares')
    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'shares.user_id')
    ->join('followers', 'followers.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->where('followers.follower_id', '=', 3)
    ->get();

Comment: I understand i started using left join but i wanted a simpler approach so i shifted to custom helper ,im asking is this bad practice ?because a db request happens evertime in a foreach loop when helper is called ?

Comment: yes definitely, you could use relationships as well